# My 2009 Chevy Malibu Ltz

Tags: chevrolet, noise, malibu

My car is smelling like it's burning metal and is making a winning sound while driving. Any advice on what it could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure we can help you with the limited information you've given us. What type of whining noise is it making (what does it sound like)? Where is it coming from (under the hood or where)? Does it change pitch as you are driving? Is it there when you're parked? Only happen when you put it in gear? Please, fill us in and we'd be glad to try and help. :o)